# Branching a subversion repository into a distributed CMS

Tags: svn, content-management-system, bazaar

I have a problem that I am not sure of the best way to tackle. I have been working on a project that requires me to go to China to do the install and integration. My code has been under subversion since the start, since that was what I knew and had used in the past. I now have concerns that I may not be able to do any checkins while I am in China.

I am thinking it might be a good idea to create a branch and use bazaar-cvs while I am away and merge the changes back into the subversion repository when I get back.

Are there any caveats that I need to be aware of? Will I be losing my commit logs? Any advice from those of you that have done a CMS conversion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the use of git-svn. It is git with svn integration. I use it for my in-house development because the remote SVN server is not always online. You get the benefits of a distributed local repository and you can easily commit your changes back to the SVN with a single command later:

`git svn dcommit`

Comment: I like it. I will be using cygwin git because bash > wincmd

Answer (score 4):

bzr-svn is the plugin for bzr that allows you to get the copy of svn trunk as bzr branch, work on it and then convert your work back to svn without losing anything. Works fine on Windows and Linux. This plugin is the part of standard windows installer (standalone installer).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but you may want to check out SVK.  It's a distributed version control based on SVN.  This allows you to do checkins and other operations while 'offline'.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVK
http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Git

http://git-scm.com/

It's a distributed CMS which has a nice migration tool to convert SVN repositories to Git. I've never used it myself but it looks very easy to use and very easy to publish a public repo on the net using different protocols.

Comment: I'd use git if it weren't a windows project. The git windows support is still too buggy for my liking.